# How does docker Images and Layers work?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-container, docker-image

Actually I am new to the Docker ecosystem and I am trying to understand how exactly does a container work on a base image? Does the base image gets loaded into the container?

I have been through Docker docs where its said that a read write container layer is formed on top of a image layer which is the container layer, but what I am confused about is image is immutable, right? Then where is the image running, is it inside the Docker engine in the VM and how the container is actually coming into play?

Comment: Why is it tagged "Azure"?

Comment: Because I was trying to deploy it in Azure Container Services, so thought maybe it will be a reference point in the discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how exactly does a container work on a base image? 
>   Does the base image gets loaded into the container?

`Docker` containers wrap a piece of software in a complete `filesystem` that contains everything needed to run: code, runtime, system tools, system libraries – anything that can be installed on a server.

Like `FreeBSD Jails` and `Solaris Zones`, Linux containers are self-contained execution environments -- with their own, isolated CPU, memory, block I/O, and network resources (Using `CGROUPS` kernel feature) -- that share the kernel of the host operating system. The result is something that feels like a virtual Machine, but sheds all the weight and startup overhead of a guest operating system.

This being said Each distribution has it's own official `docker` image (`library`), that is shipped with minimal binaries, Considered `docker`'s best practices and it's ready to build on.

> I am confused about is image is immutable, right? where is the image running, is it inside the Docker engine in the VM and how the container is actually coming into play?

`Docker` used to use `AUFS`, still uses it on `debian` and uses `AUFS` like file systems like `overlay` and etc on other distributions. `AUFS` provides layering. Each Image consists of Layers, These layers are read only. Each container has a read/write layer on top of its image layers. Read only layer are shared between containers so you will have storage space savings. Container will see the `union mount` of all image layers + read/write layer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what is still bothering me is suppose I need an apache server so i pull the image for that and then the apache image will pull the debian image because that's what its docker file suggest, so do we have a running instance of this image running on the linux kernel when we want a apache container started?

Comment: Linux Kernel is running on the `docker host`, and shared between containers. So when you pull `apache `image, layers consist of `debian` base ( Only binaries) + extra binaries for `apache` package in a layer on top of `debian`. when you create a container from that image, based on `entrypoint` command a process will be run, in your case `apache2`. In order to run this process, you need some `base binaries`, like `systemd` and   ... in debian image, and of course `apache2 `binaries in `apache2` layer on top.

Comment: Ok alright, so the image is run in docker engine in the VM OS kernel and accordingly the containers share the image based on the resource allocation and need. Now if more than one containers share the same image does that mean that the containers are layered on top of one another or is it that the containers are running in parallel?

Comment: No, They dont run on top of each other. Consider Read only image layers as files, or binaries, that can be shared in readonly format. Example: Linux binaries, Many softwares share same binaries as dependencies.